# Java Collections immutable

Tags: java, collections

This program is running fine but when I try to run the code with any of these commented-out statements it throws an *"UnsupportedOperationException"* error and I can't figure out why. I don't want to add elements to the list Individually.

```
/* 
    List<String> strings =Arrays.asList("Namste", "India", "..!"); 
    --> java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add      
*/

/*     
List<String> strings =List.of("Namste", "India", "..!");
    --> java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection.add      
*/
List<String> strings =new ArrayList<>();                
strings.add("Namaste");
strings.add("India");
strings.add("..!");
        
System.out.printf("Before : ");
for (String string : strings) 
     System.out.printf("%s ",string);
        
Methods.addAll(strings, "G","K");        

System.out.printf("\nAfter : ");
for (String string : strings) 
     System.out.printf("%s ",string);
```

Methods.addAll is defined like this:

```
public static <T> void addAll(List<T> list, T... arr) {
        for (T elt : arr) list.add(elt);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList()` and `List.of()` will both produce Lists that are immutable.

To use them for a list you would like to extend, you could do something like

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Namste", "India", "..!"));
```

Comment: The list returned by `Arrays.asList()` is not immutable, it just as a fixed length. You cannot add or remove items, but you can **replace** existing items with `set`.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with varargs or generics. The lists you're creating in the commented-out section are immutable: `ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableCollection` is, for example, an immutable collection. That means you can't change it, for example by adding to it. (`Arrays.asList` isn't fully immutable: you can replace entries via `set`, you just can't add or remove any -- the list length is immutable.)

The JavaDocs make this clear, and I'd encourage you to read them carefully as "first line of defense" when you have a question about a class's behavior. The docs for [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) specify that it's "fixed-size", while the docs for [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) describe it as an "unmodifiable list", with a link to a page describing exactly what that means.

A standard one-liner to get a mutable list is `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(your, elements, here))`. That generates the half-immutable `Arrays.asList`, and then adds its elements to a new ArrayList.